# Can subclasses in Python inherit parent class decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

If I apply a decorator to a class:

```
from flask.ext.restful import Resource

@my_decorator()
class Foo(Resource): ...
```

Will it be automatically applied to any subclass methods as well? For example, will it be *magically* applied to `a_foobar_method`?

```
class FooBar(Foo):

    def a_foobar_method(self):
        ...
```

Comment: That decorator isn't even applied to `Foo`'s methods.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 6):

In short, no.

```
@my_decorator
class Foo(Resource): ...
```

is simply shorthand for

```
class Foo(Resource): ...
Foo = my_decorator(Foo)
```

If the only time you ever use `Foo` is to define `FooBar`, then together your two pieces of code are equivalent to this:

```
class Foo(Resource): ...
Foo_decorated = my_decorator(Foo)
class FooBar(Foo_decorated):
    def a_foobar_method(self):
        ...
```

Or even to this:

```
class Foo(Resource): ...
class FooBar(my_decorator(Foo)):
    def a_foobar_method(self):
        ...
```

The real answer depends on what the decorator does. In principle it stands a chance of seeing the methods of `FooBar` if it looks at the list of methods after the class has been instantiated as an object (e.g. because it modifies the `__init__` method). But if it goes through the methods at the time it is called and applies some change to each of them, then it will have no effect on extra methods (or replaced methods) in `FooBar`.

Answer (score 1):

Decorators do not "mark" the decorated class in any way. There is no way to tell if you wrote

```
@decorator
class Foo:
    pass
```

or

```
class Foo:
    pass

Foo = decorator(Foo)
```

simply by looking at `Foo` itself. Decorators are just applied at the point of use, and then are forgotten.